# Did Ishmael return home to his father Abraham?

Tags: binding-of-isaac, yishmael, yitzchak

The Torah says, on the matter of the Akedah:

> So early next morning, Abraham saddled his ass and took with him two of his lads and his son Isaac. [Gen. 22:3]

The Midrash comments:

> His two lads were [his son] Ishmael and [his servant] Eliezer. [Leviticus Rabbah 26:7]

But hadn't Abraham banished Ishmael years before, in particular so he wouldn't have any contact with Isaac*?  What more are we told in the Sources about this return home?

*Pirkei DeRabbi Eliezer 31:5 reports a conversation between Isaac and Ishmael.

Comment: If you read further in the Pirkei DeRabbi Eliezer 30 it notes how Avraham went and visited Yishmael post-banishment. - perhaps one can say that they maintained a relationship even though he was banished and that would account for his presence?

Comment: @Dov -- This explains Abraham's desire to stay in touch with Ishmael; so he visited him where Yishmael was living.  It does not explain why Sarah allowed Yishmael to come back where Abraham and Isaac lived.